# Why does my script create extra, unwanted links?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript which creates link dynamically based on a SharePoint list that is grouped by a column "Report Category". The code is working however, if there is a empty group but has data then it should create all the links and a link called "Others". I wonder why it's creating 2 links that are "Others" along with all the other links it should create. html uploaded here https://jsfiddle.net/ea8dyvyq/5/

```
<div class="nav-report-category">
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            //$("table.ms-listviewtable td[class=’ms-gb’]").each(function() {
            //$("table.ms-listviewtable td[class^='ms-gb']").each(function(){
            $(".ms-listviewtable td[class^='ms-gb']").each(function(){  
            $(".ms-listviewtable td[class^='ms-gb']").length;
            //$("table.ms-listviewtable td.ms-gb").each(function(){         
            //$("ms-gb.td").each(function(){
            //Hide all Counts for Groups
            //$(this).find("span:last").remove();
            //alert('loop is working');
            var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-report-category")[0];
            //var liTag = document.createElement('li');
            //var aTag = document.createElement('a');

            //aTag.setAttribute("href","yourlink.htm");

            var str = $(this).text();
            str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") +1); //remove everything before :
            str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("(")); //remove counts
            //str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1);
            //$(this).find("span:last").remove();
            //var RptCat = $(".ms-listviewtable td.ms-gb:first a:eq(1)").text();
            //var grNameRaw = $(this).text().replace(RptCat+' :','');
            //var grName = grNameRaw.substring(0,grNameRaw.indexOf('(')-1).replace(/s|xA0/g,'');            
            //aTag.innerHTML = $(this).text();

            //aTag.innerHTML = str.trim();
            //aTag.setAttribute('target', '_blank');    

            if (!str.trim() || str.trim() == null) 
            {
                var liTag = document.createElement('li');
                var aTag = document.createElement('a');
                aTag.innerHTML = "Other";
            }
            else
            {
                var liTag = document.createElement('li');
                var aTag = document.createElement('a');         
                aTag.innerHTML = str.trim();
            }

            aTag.setAttribute('target', '_blank');  
            //var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var link = window.location.href + "&RC=" + str.trim();
            aTag.setAttribute("href",link);

            liTag.appendChild(aTag);
            mydiv.appendChild(liTag);           
            //mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
            //mydiv.appendChild(document.createElement ("span"));
            //mydiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "));

        });
        //alert('test');

    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML

Comment: sorry. Updated the post with html, jquery and css thru jsfiddle